# Handle update forms in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

What is the proper way to handle editing objects in Spring MVC. Let's say I have user object:

```
public class User {
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    //Lets assume here are next 10 fields...


    //getters and setters
}
```

Now in my controller I have GET and POST for url: user/edit/{id}

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/edit/{user_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editUser(@PathVariable Long user_id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("userForm", userService.getUserByID(user_id));
    return "/panels/user/editUser";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/user/edit/{user_id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm,
            BindingResult result, @PathVariable String user_id, Model model) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        User user = userService.getById(user_id);
        user.updateFields(userForm);
    }
    userService.update(user);
}
```

Now the question is do I really need to get my user from database in POST method and update every field one by one in some update method or is there better way for that?

I am thinking about using @PathVariable for User and get User from database with converter and then in some way inject parameters from POST method into that object automatically. Something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/edit/{user}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editUser(@Valid @PathVariable("user") User userForm,
    BindingResult result, Model model)
```

But when I try this I got error with BindingResults:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be declared immediately after the model attribute, the @RequestBody or the @RequestPart arguments

Is there any easy way to create controller to handle objects editing or do I need to copy fields which could change one by one??

By the way, I can't use SessionAttributes because it causes problems for multiple tabs.

Comment: If y ou come find a nice solution for this please share it as i have been looking at the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are sending "userForm" as a model attribute. If so try with following pattern,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/edit/{user_id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editUser(@PathVariable String user_id, @Valid @ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm,
BindingResult result, Model model)
```

Thanks

Comment: I missed part with pathVariable but thats not the point. Read my question again, my problem is that i want update object without need to copy each field one by one..

Answer (score 0):

You keep user id in a input hidden inside your edit form.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm,
    BindingResult result,Model model){

 if(result.hasErrors()){

    User user = userService.getById(userForm.getId());
    user.updateFields(userForm);
 }
 userService.update(user);
 return "redirect:.......";
}
```